# Minimum value of line concerning hyperbolic functions

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The point P on the curve y=coshx has abscissa x>0. The tangent at P cuts the x-axis at T and the normal to the curve at P cuts the x-axis at N. At what value of x is TN a minimum?

So I attempted to first work out the general coordinates for T, which I got to be (sinhx+c,0) and N which I got as (-1/(sinhx) + c, 0). Is this correct so far? Any advice on how I should proceed?

Answer (score 2):

That is a cool problem.
Let us denote as $p$ the $x$-coordinate of the point $P$.

Okay, so I got the following equations for the tangent and the normal at $P$:
$T_P(x)= \sinh(p)x+c$, where $c=\cosh(p) - p\sinh(p)$.
$N_P(x)= \frac{-1}{\sinh(p)}x+d$, where $d=\cosh(p)+\frac{p}{\sinh(p)}$.

Next, we solve for $T_P(x)=0$ and $N_P(x)=0$ to find the $x$-intercepts of these two lines.
$T = \frac{-c}{\sinh(p)} = \frac{p\sinh(p)-\cosh(p)}{\sinh(p)}$ and
$N = {d}\sinh(p) =  \cosh(p)\sinh(p)+p$

You are interested in the minimum of $F=\overline{TN}=N-T$,
so after spending some quality time differentiating you will get to the following equation for the critical points
$\frac{dF}{dp} = 2 \cosh^2(p) - \frac{1}{\tanh^2(p)} = 0$.

Here are the steps: http://bit.ly/17MWzE5
(Weird why `sympy` can't solve this simple equation...)

Solving by hand we find $\sinh^2(p) = \frac{1}{2}$, which gives $p=\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\approx 0.6584789$.

Comment: @amWhy -- well I knew I was _very close_ to the solution, so I figured my answer would help the OP. Indeed, there was only a sign mistake which I now fixed.

Comment: +1 for responding and updating your post! (And for a nice answer!)

Comment: Thank you so much. How did you work out the constants c and d? Thanks again

Comment: No worries, was just being negligent!